# Perl Net::FTP package PASV Command not implemented

Tags: perl

I wrote the below FTP client program in perl. Which is executing fine in one server. If I try to execute the same in different server i'm getting PASV command not implemented error. If I give Passive=>0 in the FTP constructor i'm getting ALLO Command not implemented. Could you please tell why i'm getting this error and how to resolve this error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;           # Don't forget !
use Net::FTP;
my $host = "X.X.X.X";
my $user = "abc";
my $password = "xxx";

my $f = Net::FTP->new($host,Debug=>1) or die "Can't open $host $@\n";
$f->login($user, $password) or die "Can't log $user in\n", $f->message;
$f->binary();
$f->put("abc.txt"); # or die "unable to send the file",$f->message;
$f->quit or die "unbale to close the conenction";
```

--- Below is the output:

```
Net::FTP>>> Net::FTP(2.79)
Net::FTP>>>   Exporter(5.58)
Net::FTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.30)
Net::FTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.29)
Net::FTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.29)
Net::FTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.25)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)<<< 220 X.X.X.X FTP server ready.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)>>> USER abc
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)<<< 331 Password required for abc.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)>>> PASS ....
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)<<< 230 User abc logged in.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)>>> TYPE I
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)<<< 200 Type set to I.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)>>> PORT X,X,X,X,221,251
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)<<< 200 PORT command successful.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)>>> ALLO 1442
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x99cabe8)<<< 502 ALLO command not implemented.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x86d9be8)>>> QUIT
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x86d9be8)<<< 221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: You haven't shown the actual error message, but I think it's the SERVER that doesn't implement PASV.

Comment: Yes. Sever is not implement the PASV. But in this code if I use Passive=>0 which will turn off pasv transfer. In this case, i'm getting "unable to send the file ALLO command not found" error. Any suggestion why its coming? how to rectify this error?

Comment: $f->put("abc.txt") this return false for me! after ALLO it didn't send the STOR command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i'm getting PASV command not implemented error

In this case the server does not implement PASV, so you cannot use passive mode, e.g. you must set transfer mode to active to transfer data.

> i'm getting ALLO Command not implemented

Also not implemented by the server, but in this case you can safely ignore this error. ALLO is just use to reserve enough space for the file to transfer and lots of servers don't implement this. The following file transfer should still work.

Edit: with Net::FTP 2.79 the return code for ALLO will no longer being ignored, but result in failure and the transfer will not be done. This means, that servers which don't correctly implement RFC959 (FTP) will stop working, because according to this RFC a server not needing to pre-allocate storage with ALLO should make this command behave the same as NOOP, e.g. return success.

Comment: ALLO command not implemented error is occurred while sending the file. In this case it wont send the file to the ftp server  right?

Comment: @user3754887: no, it should still send the file because Net::FTP knows that the error with ALLO can be ignored. The sending is done with a STOR command, so check for a successful STOR command after the ALLO in debug. Also, `put` should return success.

Comment: $f->put("abc.txt") this return false for me!

Comment: @user3754887: could you please add the output of your program to your question, with `Debug => 1` (not DEBUG, but Debug). That would make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I added the output along with the problem statement. hope it will be helpful! and Thanks for notifying "Debug".

Comment: @user3754887: With version 2.79 Net::FTP now treats an error response from ALLO as error, with earlier versions it worked because it ignored the response. According to RFC959 ALLO should behave as NOOP (e.g. just return ok) if the server does not need to pre-allocate storage. So in a way Net::FTP behaves right, while the server does not implement the specification (RFC959). What kind of server is this?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Just before I copied the earlier version of Net::FTP and executed its worked fine. FTP server is the customized one. There they implemented only limited commands.

Answer (score 0):

According to the perldoc, the pasv_xfer command will activate passive mode. From [that page](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html):

> ```
> pasv_xfer ( SRC_FILE, DEST_SERVER [, DEST_FILE ] )
>        This method will do a file transfer between two remote ftp servers.
>        If "DEST_FILE" is omitted then the leaf name of "SRC_FILE" will be
>        used.
> ```